# Получение списка пользователей определённой роли ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2

Имеется база данных, в которой содержится список пользователей, созданных при помощи Identity. Каждый пользователь принадлежит определённой роли. Роли находятся в другой таблице, и, следовательно, связывается это через другую таблицу.
Как получить список пользователей с конкретной роли, обращаясь к этой таблице, где ID пользователя и ID его роли? Не представляю, как сделать запрос, потому что ни разу не работал с EF...

Comment: А можно как-то уточнить какая таблица эта а какая та?

Comment: @qzavyer, при инициализации базы, в ней создались таблицы AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles, AspNetUserRoles - типичная связь многие-ко-многим. И вот мне нужно из AspUsers получить пользователей, у которых конкретная роль. То бишь, как я представляю, взять название роли, найти её Id, из таблицы AspNetUserRoles взять Id пользователей по этой роли и вывести о них информацию из AspNetUsers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));

string roleName = "Admin";
var role = await roleManager.Roles.SingleAsync(r => r.Name == roleName);

var users = userManager.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == role.Id));
```